# how to get url variables in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

I am creating ajax request with type get, I have passed the variables to the url and request is working fine. Now I have created a new button and want to get the current url variables by click on that button to do further process.
Variables are not showing in browser url but in ajax request url. How can I get those variables on click?

[See the screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hdbfcu)

```
 function pagi_ajax(records_per_page){

 var data = 'action=' + 'testing_ajax' + '&records_per_page=' + records_per_page;

    var url_string = window.location.href;
    console.log(url_string);

 $.ajax({
     url: "ajax_pagi.php",
     dataType: "json",
     type: "get",         
     data: data, 

success: function (result) {

    }
  });
}

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pagi_ajax(records_per_page);">Next</a>
<button class="pagi_button" onclick="pagi_ajax( <?php echo $records_per_page; ?>, 
 <?php echo $rec_limit[$i]; ?>, 
 <?php echo $total_records; ?>)"> <?php echo $i+1; ?> </button>
```

Comment: sorry if I'm misunderstanding - what happens if you console.dir(result) within the success function? You should see what is coming out of the server side if you do that.

Comment: I am creating pagination and on next I want to get the current url variables and run another ajax request for the next record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the variables, "records_per_page" is how you're creating the url.

To pass it to another function you can add a function call in your success call and pass the variables you need.

```
function pagi_ajax(records_per_page){

    var data = 'action=' + 'testing_ajax' + '&records_per_page=' + records_per_page;

    var url_string = window.location.href;
    console.log(url_string);

    $.ajax({
         url: "ajax_pagi.php",
         dataType: "json",
         type: "get",         
         data: data, 

    success: function (result, records_per_page) {
        // Your code here
        console.log(records_per_page)
        }
});
```

Comment: records_per_page is just for you to understand my question, I want to get it from url how to get it from url, please see screenshot

Comment: So here:
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pagi_ajax(records_per_page);">Next</a>

You don't have records_per_page?

Comment: by clicking on button I am sending records_per_page

Comment: but when I click on next I want variable from current url and run another request with newly added values to the record_per_page

Comment: So you have records_per_page when you click, and you are able to pass it?

Comment: Yes when I click on <button> and I want to get when I click on Next which is another button

Comment: Okay I think we're not understanding each other. In pagi_ajax(records_per_page); are you **ABLE** to pass records_per_page, or are you **NOT ABLE** to pass records_per_page

Comment: Yes I am able to pass that

Comment: Please see updated answer, all you need to do is add "records_per_page" as a parameter in your success function, then you can use it within that function as you please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159494/discussion-between-nick-taylor-and-mackija).

Answer (score 0):

While the URL of the current page is available through the `location` object, there is no standard API for accessing URLs that you have used to make HTTP requests with `XMLHttpRequest`.

If you want to get that information, then you have to store it somewhere yourself.

In this case, it looks like you already have that information stored in the global `records_per_page` variable. So use that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally some kind of variables like : `recordPerPage` should be a constance and store somewhere. If not you can cache that variable on `pagi_ajax` function and retrieve it for later use.

You can cache that variable via service like this:

```
  pagingInfo = (function(){
    var info = {
      recordsPerPage: 10
    } 
    var get = function(){
      return info;
    }
    var setrecordsPerPage = function(value){
      info.recordsPerPage = value;
    }
    return {
      get: get,
      setrecordsPerPage: setrecordsPerPage
    }
  })()

  function pagi_ajax(records_per_page){
    pagingInfo.setrecordsPerPage(records_per_page);
  }

  function handleClick(){
    var recordsPerPage = pagingInfo.get().recordsPerPage
  }
```